ASP.NET Core / C# code to test HTTP reponse MIME types for code or HTML
I can't find an ASP.NET Core / C# function or code example to test if a HTTP response is programmatic.
In ASP.NET Core 8.0 using C#, I am determining if a web response is html or javascript with
if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode < 400 &&
    (context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Contains("text/javascript") ||
     context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Contains("application/javascript") ||
     context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Contains("text/html") ||
     context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Contains("text/xml")
    ))
{ 
    // Proceed with operations on replies that might be programmatic
}

This does work on the websites I tried (an admittedly very poor sample of less than a dozen websites).
I should note that I'm not doing security related code, so I am OK trusting the ContentType. I'm not trying to determine if someone is maliciously altering the headers.
The most obvious problem is I would think I am missing relatively common client side applications (I'm only testing for (x)html and Javascript). Browsers and extensions might run python? jQuery might not use application/javascript MIME type sometimes? I don't know. (I'm not testing for Java code, but am uncertain if that is an issue, without a Java plugin).
Also, the above code seems pretty inefficient (faster try is below). Is there some function or library out there that will do this quicker? I searched in stackoverflow and generally googled but my searches aren't finding anything.
More efficient code, but less accuracy could be a problem:
string mimePrefix, mimeSuffix, mimeScript;

if (null != context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType &&
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Length >= 8)
{
    mimePrefix = context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Substring(0, 5); // "text/"
    mimeSuffix = context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Substring(5, 3); // First three chars after "text/", so this would be "htm" for "text/html"

    if (context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Length < 22) 
        mimeScript = "";
    else             // find "application/javascript" if present
        mimeScript = context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType.Substring(0, 22);
}
else
{
    mimePrefix = mimeSuffix = mimeScript = "";
}

if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode < 400 &&
    ("text/" == mimePrefix && 
     ("jav" == mimeSuffix || "htm" == mimeSuffix || "xml" == mimeSuffix)
    ) 
    || "application/javascript" == mimeScript
   )
{ 
    // Proceed with operations on replies that might be programmatic
}

Again, just wondering if there is some function or library I should be using, or if there is a better coding algorithm that be more accurate or faster, or better in other ways.

it's not clear why you are doing this, but it should be noted that only browsers read this, and only in the context of "nosniff" to prevent XSS/injections via SRC's of script or style tags.  (the browser will block the request if it doesn't match either style or script mime-type) Every other context will be based on extension.  Python and Java do not run in the browser... only Javascript and WebAssembly can run in the browser.  HTML is not really "programmatic"... it's just markup.

You could try HashSet<string> for efficience as it will avoid the string judgement. In this case the third party library won't be necessary.

@browsemator: This is running on a proxy and will temporarily change URIs in the body of html, scripts because of a maintenance issue (there's a reason we don't want to use 301s).

sounds like you just want to filter by extension.  (different filetypes have different paths?)
